# Set a mysql table to Javascript variable using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a mysql table with `'user_name'` and `'user_round'`. I want the 'user_round' to be set to whatever the value of `'Level'` (this is a javascript variable). My code brings up errors like POST 404 not found. Here is what I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js"></script>
var <?php echo $_SESSION['user_name']; ?>; //Without this I get username not defined error?
var Level =  1;
function Fail() {
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "phpfiles/savestage.php",
   data: {
      name: '<?php echo $_SESSION['user_name']; ?>',
      stage: Level
   },
   success: function() {
       console.log("Finished uploading stage");
   }
});
```

Here is my php page:

```
<?php 
  include 'connect.php';

  $sql="INSERT INTO DB NAME (user_round, user_name) VALUES ('$stage', '$name')";

  $result = mysql_query($sql, $cn) or
        die(mysql_error($cn));
?>
```

Comment: Do you mean in the PHP page you are getting only one variable i.e. `$_POST['name']`?

Comment: Well the page says it was successful (it isn't), but what I mean is when I inspect element and click sources, This is what it looks like:
   data: {
      name: 'ActualUsernameIsHere',
      stage: Level
..etc

Answer (score 0):

I've made a test here and the inspector says the ajax posted variable Level with value of 1

```
<script>
var Level =  1;
function Fail() {
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "phpfiles/savestage.php",
data: {
name: 'test_name',
stage: Level
},
success: function() {
console.log("Finished uploading stage");
}
});
}
Fail();
</script>
```

Comment: that's strange, it doesn't seem to work for me.. I even tried using test_name instead of user name, under sources it still shows 'Level' instead of the value. I get the Finished uploading stage message but MySQL database doesn't change. Is there a problem with my php page? I have tried different approaches.

Comment: Where might the error be? My savestage.php is in the question